# Why ansible evaluate variables which is not used in playbook?

Tags: python, ansible

I am using ansible 2.3.1.1 with jenkins. I have encountered the following issue - my playbook which uses variables from aws dynamic inventory becomes extremely slow. The most interesting case that if I copy this playbook outside my jenkins workspace and run in any other directory the execution speed is OK. In order to test it I remove all variable files from workspace directory /group_vars/all - after that the execution speed for this playbook inside workspace become OK too. 
So, as I understand ansible calculate all variables from group_vars/all even if they are not used in current playbook. So could someone explain why ansible does so and how it could be tuned?

the playbook is the following

============

- hosts: "x.x.x.x"

tasks:

```
 - name: print something
  debug:
    var: hostvars["{{item}}"]['ec2_vpc_id']
  with_items: "{{groups['some_tag']}}"
```

============

Answer (score 0):

This is how thinks work in current version. Avoid `hostvars`.

You can track progress on this issues [23349](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23349) and [17528](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17528).

Comment: But as I have said, If I run playbook outside workspace the hostvars is ok, even if i use it in very tricky jinja templates, so it seem that issue not hostvars itself, but in the evaluating of all variables in /group_vars/all for each run in the loop

Comment: Hmm... unsure what you mean. Ansible parses complete inventory – creates host list, then parses all inventory variables (all that are available in current workspace) and applies them to all hosts in the list. It can be quite time consuming on initial step if you have huge host list and a lot of vars files. But this should not influence individual tasks execution time. If you use only a fraction of inventory/variables in your playbooks, you should consider refactoring your inventory.

Comment: "But this should not influence individual tasks execution time" - The issue is exact this case. It seems that ansible evaluates all the variables for each task and for each iteration in the loops

Comment: Also as I understand ansible uses lazy variable evaluation, so variables which are not used in playbook should not be evaluated at all